# How to update object in Mobx observable array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

Codesandbox to the problem:
https://codesandbox.io/s/serverless-thunder-6gj04?file=/src/store.js

I have the following store:

```js
class PersonStore {
  persons = [];

  constructor() {
    makeAutoObservable(this, {}, { autoBind: true });
  }

  *fetchPersons() {
    const response = yield fetch(
      "https://random-data-api.com/api/users/random_user?size=5"
    );

    this.persons = yield response.json();
  }
}

export default new PersonStore();
```

Now, I want to update persons inside the person-list.

When I update a single field on on items inside the array like this it works as expected and the UI updates:

```js
  update(id) {
    let updated = this.persons.find((p) => p.id === id);

    // This works...
    updated.first_name = "FOO";
  }
```

However, in the future I would like to pass more complex, updated data into this function. So my idea was to basically assign a totally new object with the updated values in the list.

Unfortunately, this does not work as I expected it:

```js
  update(id) {
    let updated = this.persons.find((p) => p.id === id);

    // This does not work...
    const dummy_person = { first_name: 'foo', last_name: 'bar', id: 99 }
    updated = dummy_person
  }
```

My first guess was that this does not work because the objects inside the array are not "normal objects" but observables. So I created a model for the persons:

```js
class Person {
  id = null;
  first_name = "";
  last_name = "";

  constructor() {
    makeAutoObservable(this);
    this.first_name = "FOO";
    this.last_name = "BAR";
  }
}
```

...but this does still not work...

```js
  update(id) {
    let updated = this.persons.find((p) => p.id === id);

    // This does not work...
    const dummy_person = new Person()
    updated = person
  }
```

How can I "replace" an object inside the array here with an object containing the updated data?

Comment: When you write `updated = dummy_person` you are only updating the `updated` reference with a new value. MobX is not involved at that stage. You could try something like this instead: `let updatedIndex = this.persons.findIndex((p) => p.id === id); this.persons.splice(updatedIndex, 1, dummy_person);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Tholle said in the comment, you are only updating local variable, not actual object.

In simpler words this is what's happening inside your `update` function:

1. `let updated = this.persons.find((p) => p.id === id);` - you create local variable `updated` and assign some object (person) to it
2. `const dummy_person = { first_name: 'foo', last_name: 'bar', id: 99 }` - you create dummy object and assign it to local `dummy_person` constant
3. `updated = dummy_person` - here you assign `dummy_person` value to `updated` variable. Basically you only reassign value of `updated` variable, you are not changing the person-object, but only changing to what value `updated` variable points.

Sometimes people explain it with boxes, like imagine that `updated` is a box and at first you put `person` inside of it and then changed you mind and put `dummy_person` inside, but actual `person` wasn't changed.

So what can you do?

As @Tholle said, you can use `splice` to change `persons` array, it will basically throw away old person and insert new one.

Or if you actually want to update old person you could use `Object.assign(updated, dummy_person)`

Or you could use `map` (although it will reassign whole array, might be unnecessary sometimes):

```
  update(id) {
    const dummy_person = { first_name: 'foo', last_name: 'bar', id: 99 };

    this.persons = this.persons.map(person => person.id === id ? dummy_person : person);
  }
```

There is a lot what you can do, depends on what you what. The main thing is understand how reactivity works!

More about this topic in the docs: https://mobx.js.org/understanding-reactivity.html

Comment: Hi Danila, thanks for your response. I think I understand what you said. Just one follow up question. You said "you are only updating local variable, not actual object."  ...but why is the first approach where I just did `updated.first_name = "FOO"` working then when it's supposed to be a local variable only?!

Comment: Because with first approach you are actually accessing ("dotting into") person object property. Basically you are saying "change `first_name` of something that `updated` box helds"